# How to write into Drive application data folder?

Tags: android, file, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata) for writing on Drive from Android. I have a file on the internal storage, and I want to copy it on Drive, like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write("hello");
fos.close();
```

The section "Inserting a file into the Application Data folder" of the tutorial says:

```
// File's content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
  return file;
//...
```

How should I do?

EDIT: I would expect this code to work, but it does not:

```
// File's content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileContent);
fos.write("hello");
fos.close();
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
  return file;
//...
```

EDIT:

I get these error, both of which I don't know how to solve:

```
04-15 12:12:24.615: W/AbstractGoogleClient(2272): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
04-15 12:12:24.615: I/System.out(2272): An error occured: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /filename: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What's wrong with the example on the "nserting a file into the Application Data folder" section. Basically, you create a new file and set its parent to appdata and insert it with an API call.

Comment: Programmatically, it look rights and it works. What's the error message you're receiving? Is your access token authorized to access "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata" scope?

Comment: Your're receiving a `FileNotFoundException`, this has nothing related with Drive SDK. I'd suggest you to edit this question and ask Android community. I think you need to remount the file system read-write, it seems like your file system is read-only at the moment. (Just saying, I'm not familiar with Android internals...)

Comment: I'm receiving this error because I'm not using the APIs the way they are meant to. The "internal storage" of Android isn't accessible at "File" level, but only at "FileOutputStream" level (see my first code snippet). And this brings back my original question: besides the example for image files, how can I transfer a "private" (for my application) file to Drive? It makes perfectly sense that the "private" files are copied to Drive on a private folder, as this should be the primary use case for the Appdata folder. But I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Could you please share them on a gist? The appdata samples are not Android specific, that's why Java sample doesn't cover this use case. I'm sorry, this should have been covered.

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5388752

Comment: @michelemarcon
Which gradle file we need to use ?