# How to read from Drive application data folder?

Tags: android, file, google-api, google-drive-api

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966480/how-to-write-into-drive-application-data-folder). I have written my data file on Drive application folder, now the same app that created these files needs to retrieve them.

This doesn't work (I get the listing of the file, but the request of file download return with a 401 error):

```
private ArrayList<File> listFilesInApplicationDataFolder(Drive service) throws IOException {
  ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
Files.List request = service.files().list();
request.setQ("'appdata' in parents");

do {
  try {
    FileList files = request.execute();

    result.addAll(files.getItems());
    request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    request.setPageToken(null);
  }
} while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
         request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

for (File file:result){
    System.out.println("##### "+file.getOriginalFilename()+ " "+file.toPrettyString());


    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
          try {
            HttpResponse resp =
                service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                    .execute();
            InputStream in= resp.getContent();
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("pinmemo",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            while(in.available()>0)
                fos.write(in.read());
            fos.close();
          } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
              startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
              return null;
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        } else {
          // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
          return null;
        }


}

return result;
```

}

What should I do?

EDIT:

I get this error message:

```
04-17 11:19:30.614: W/System.err(2022): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
04-17 11:19:30.614: W/System.err(2022): at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1095)
```

EDIT: the new Google play games services basically covers my needs (the only problem is that my app isn't a game...), therefore this question is now partially obsolete. Of course, Google play games uses "Cloud save" instead of "drive", but for my needs that's sufficent. However, should I use Google play games for non-gaming app?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your access token has permissions for the appdata scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

Comment: Already done that: [code] credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata");[/code] (this is the same code I used for writing)

Comment: There was a known issue 2 days ago with auth backends. This should have been fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. I also tried to remove the old file, create a new one but I still get 401 when trying to read.

Comment: Validate your access token to see if the problem is the token's itself: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent?hl=en#validatetoken

Comment: I would gladly do it, but I really don't know how to do that... :(((

Comment: Make a request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token]

Comment: The Drive API shields me from getting the access token directly (or, I don't know how to get it).